# Is it possible to see the data of a post request (grpc request) in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, grpc, grpc-web

I use a HTTPS website in internet that JavaScript frameworks is `vue.js` and the website send post request over `grpc-web`.

When I'm trying to see request body on network tab in browser(Firefox or chrome), request body looks like this(non human readable):

`\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000B\n\u0014\rë\u0011B\u0015\...`
[image]

I want to know what content is posted in the request payload?

Note: response content not need for me, I want just request payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `Fiddler Everywhere` App in trial mode and inspecting gRPC requests as shown as:

[image: first step]

[image: second step]

---

Then I find the request body in hex decimal and I can convert hex decimal to any format (base64,binary, ...)

[image: final step]

For more information click on [this link](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/knowledge-base/capturing-grpc-traffic).

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome plugin for help decoding grpc-web payloads into readable formats, which might be to help:

https://github.com/SafetyCulture/grpc-web-devtools

Comment: thanks, I installed this extension on Firefox and chrome but not work.